# Reject access to specific URLs for all the ROLEs in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

This is my spring-security.xml

```
  <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard.htm"  access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_DEMO')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/dash/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_DEMO')"/>

        <form-login login-page="/index.htm" 
        default-target-url="/dashboard.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.htm" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" invalidate-session="true" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="customUserService" class="edu.am.bigdata.web.service.impl.CustomUserServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5"> </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
 </beans:beans>
```

how to prevent access to one particular Url???
I have some controller functions (i.e.) urls - **/dash/* , /algo/***

I need to prevent this url even if user possess any ROLE and show it as access Denied only if he directly access these urls. But my web application internally uses this URL. 
If I type this url manually like localhost:8080/MyApp/dash/viz.htm, this should show access denied. For any Roles these urls should not be accessed.. How can I do this ???

Answer (score 1):

Use access = "denyAll". For example:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="denyAll" />
```